# Notificaciones push entre usuarios

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

¿Alguien sabe cómo implementar notificaciones push automáticamente entre dos usuarios o más tipo WhatsApp? Es decir, cuando un usuario escriba algo en parsee (lo tengo en AWS), se genere una notificación automáticamente para otro usuario solamente (no para todos los usuarios de la app) ni tenga yo que enviarla (lo haga automáticamente) y cuando el usuario receptor lo recibe, que al leer el mensaje ya desaparezca las futuras notificaciones. Sistema iOS con Xcode swift 3.0. Es imposible encontrar esto en tutoriales.

Comment: Utiliza firebase para esa tarea, al momento de cargar tu app, se genera un tocken de firebase messages con el que  podrás individualizar los envíos de push, solo lo almacenas en el perfil del usuario y cada que este reciba un mensaje, le notificas a través de su tocken

Comment: Buenos días: y para Parse Sever en AWS sería lo mismo? Conoces algún link de ejemplo para ver cómo implementarlo? Puedo utilizar Parse server en AWS y notificaciones a través de Firebase a la vez? Un saludo

Comment: Aqui tienes como implementar [Parse Server en AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/mobile/how-to-set-up-parse-server-on-aws-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk/) por otro lado, va a depender del lenguaje que vallas a correr en tu servidor, firebase se adapta a C, android, IOS, php, javascript, node entre otros

Comment: Actualmente me encuentro desarrollando una aplicacion de mensajeria instantanea desde 0, para este sistema estoy utilizando MySQL, NodeJS, servidor Ubuntu y lo mas importante, un websocket, en mi caso Socket.IO que cuenta con una libreria bastante buena para Swift.